# replace with regular expression python

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have numeric strings in fortran format that look like this `0.1245-102`
float conversion doesn't work because format is not expected : `0.1245e-102`

I use this command

`re.sub(r"[0-9]-[0-9]",r"e-","0.1245-102")`

I 'm very new to regular expression and with this way i obtain `0.124e-02`
how can i keep `5e-1` in new result ?

Comment: Why not simply `'0.1245-102'.replace('-', 'e-')`?

Comment: @PavelAnossov -- fails for negative numbers

Comment: @ANSWERERS -- Other ways which these numbers *could* possibly appear (I think):  `1-10`, `1.-10`, `-1-10` -- I think the accepted solution should handle these just in case ...

Comment: What do positive exponents look like? `1E10`?  `1+10`?

Comment: 'e-'.join('0.1245-102'.rsplit('-',1)) ?

Comment: @cmd -- This works if they're 1 number per string.  good suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
r'(?<=\d|\.)-(?=\d)'
```

which matches a `-` if there are digits or a dot) before, and digits after.

Demo:

```
>>> exponent = re.compile(r'(?<=\d|\.)-(?=\d)')
>>> exponent.sub('e-', '0.1245-102')
'0.1245e-102'
>>> float(exponent.sub('e-', '0.1245-102'))
1.245e-103
>>> float(exponent.sub('e-', '1-10'))
1e-10
>>> float(exponent.sub('e-', '1.-10'))
1e-10
>>> float(exponent.sub('e-', '-1-10'))
-1e-10
```

To handle both `-` and `D+` (negative and positive exponents), you could use:

```
r'(?<=\d|\.)D?(?=(?:\+|-)\d)
```

which would allow for and replace an optional `D`, leaving the `-` or `+` in place when replacing:

```
>>> exponent = re.compile(r'(?<=\d|\.)D?(?=(?:\+|-)\d)')
>>> float(exponent.sub('e', '0.1245-102'))
1.245e-103
>>> float(exponent.sub('e', '456D+5'))
45600000.0
```

This *does* allow for the `D` to also precede the `-`, so `0.1245D-102` would be valid too, but it simplifies the replacement handling.

Comment: yes it sounds like this . I forgot positives exponent look like this "456D+5"

Comment: yes but it fails for positif have i to include this call in a try - except test ? or is there other thing to do with compile function ?

Comment: What do your positive exponents *look* like? You can do a `try: except:` or first test if there is a match.

Comment: positives are for example "456D+5"

Comment: @froggy: So `D+` needs to be replaced with `e`?

Comment: ;) I mean is there a other thing to add to compile expression not to have to test explicitely if it matches or to avoid managing error when there is nothing to change